# Cucumber Data Table in (Nightwatch) javascript not working as expected

Tags: javascript, cucumber, nightwatch.js, gherkin

So the problem I'm getting is probably something so, so simple (probably), but it's infuriating my as to why it won't work.

What I'd like to do is click on an Edit button on a website, change a value, and Save it.

However, there are over 120 of these changes to be made, and thus over 120 edit clicks, etc.

Hence why I thought I'd use a Data Table.

[image]

And here is my subsequent test code;

```
const { client } = require('nightwatch-cucumber')
const { defineSupportCode } = require('cucumber')
const globals = require('../../config/globals.js')

var emailEntry = (`input[name='administrator[email]']`)
var passwordEntry = (`input[name='administrator[password]']`)
var existingGtmKey = ("GTM-123456")
var newGtmKey = ("GTM-654321")
var gtmKey = (`//div/input[@value='${existingGtmKey}']`)
var saveButton = (`input[type=submit][value='Save']`)


defineSupportCode(({ Given, Then, When }) => {

Given(/^I've logged into Winit cms$/, () => {
return client
.url('http://winit-stage.bauerpublishing.com/admin/sign_in')
.waitForElementVisible('body', 5000)
// Enter winit email address
.moveToElement(`form#new_administrator ${emailEntry}`, 1,1)
.click(`form#new_administrator ${emailEntry}`)
.setValue(`${emailEntry}`, "*****.*****@*****.co.uk")
// Enter winit password
.moveToElement(`form#new_administrator ${passwordEntry}`, 1,1)
.click(`form#new_administrator ${passwordEntry}`)
.setValue(`${passwordEntry}`, "******")
// Click on the 'Sign in' button 
.click("form#new_administrator input[type=submit][value='Sign in']")
})

Then (/^I'm able to change the gtm tag for that site (.*?)$/, 
(siteedit) => {
return client
// Click on the 'sites' link
.useXpath()
.click("//a[normalize-space(text())='Sites']")
// Click on Edit button
.click(siteedit)
.click(`${gtmKey}`)
.clearValue(`${gtmKey}`)
// Set new gtm key value
.setValue(`${gtmKey}`, `${newGtmKey}`)
// Click save
.useCss()
.click(`${saveButton}`)
})
})
```

I thought (wrongly!) this would be pretty straightforward, the script would log into my account, click the edit button, enter new value, press the save key, then do the same for the next website edit button.

It works for the first edit button in the Data table, but then the test fails, giving the following error;

[image]

So it looks as though it's running the **whole** script, and not just the ***Then*** part of the script.

But I don't understand why??

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you provide your feature file?

Comment: Sorry, I added the wrong image at the top of the post! Apologies. I've now added the feature file...